# How to display information on map in kibana without having one geopoint per document?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have logs regarding buildings stored in Elasticsearch (temperatures, door opening, lights, movement detectors...). Each building have its own uid. I want to display information on a map. Those buildings are very unlikely to move ( :-) ) so I think it is stupid to enrich each document with GPS coordinates that will then be grouped at query time.

Is it possible to create such a thing as a side index containing all the building uid and coordinates so we can do a join ?

Comment: Having an index that maps a building UID to a location is pretty much the same as having the location field inside the building document, don't you think? It's not stupid at all to store the location of each building, it's how you have to do it if you want to map that into Kibana.

Comment: @Val No it is not the same. There are milions of documents for each building. I changed the question a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: Same answer :-)

Comment: Please @Val read again. Storing the building position each time someone open a door in the building is just stupid.

Comment: Believe me, I've re-read your question again earlier. Still same answer... You should consider each event as a standalone event and in this respect it should contain the location if you ever want to map it in Kibana. If you are tempted to have a single document per building and add all events in a nested list as they come, well, Kibana doesn't support anything nested. So if you thought that ES could do JOINs like a RDBMS, then you picked the wrong technology (i.e. the ES stack) I'm afraid.